# NameError: Global name 'TouchAction' is not defined in android automation by appium python

Tags: android, automation, appium, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

While performing this code for automating android app using appium python client,

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Hello')
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.tap(el).perform()
```

Its giving error saying "NameError: global name 'TouchAction' is not defined". What am I missing?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution anyway. I didn't find what package to import earlier. After I added this ""from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction"" in code, it works!

Answer (score 10):

You have to add the import package at the beginning:

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
```